# SpamAssassin MISSING_MIMEOLE rule

Tags: email, spam, php, spamassassin

Im sending out mails that spamassasin are quite harsh on - one of the biggest minusses it gives is:

```
  0.0 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_06    BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image area
 -1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1% [score: 0.0000]
  1.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24     BODY: HTML: images with 2000-2400 bytes of words
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  0.8 RDNS_NONE              Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
**1.9 MISSING_MIMEOLE        Message has X-MSMail-Priority, but no X-MimeOLE
```

I look it up and it says:

> SpamAssassin Rule: MISSING_MIMEOLE
>
> Standard description: Message has X-MSMail-Priority, but no X-MimeOLE
>
> Explanation
>
> The message is pretending to be generated by a Microsoft email program
>   which uses the extension header X-MSMail-Priority, but is missing the
>   extension header X-MimeOLE which is characteristic of Microsoft email.
>
> This suggests that the sender is using badly-written mailout software,
>   rather than a genuine Microsoft email program.

I use htmlmimemail5 on apache servers on ubuntu - and I dont want to use freaking microsoft mailsendout software - how do I avoid getting those 1.9 points? (i need under 2 points to not go into spam filter)

Comment: Putting the threshold at score 2 is pretty harsh.  SpamAssassin defaults to a somewhat higher threshold.

Comment: ah - it was just a user who said our mails came to the spamfolder - so one could hope that its a rare occasion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put in the `X-MSMail-Priority:` either, and you're home free.

More generally, don't copy / paste email headers; put in only headers you know are needed, and which you know the purpose of.  Spammers don't, and if you act like the spammers, you get what you deserve (or, at the very least, you are considered acceptable collateral damage).